# to check if KSOAP2 web-service is up and running

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

```
    private String METHOD_NAME = "schedule";
    private String NAMESPACE = "http://calculate.backend.web.org";
    private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME; 
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.4:8080/AndroidBackEnd/services/Calculate?wsdl";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("username",username);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
            Object result = envelope.getResponse();
```

How to verify if the WEB-SERVICE is up and running from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web-service is down, then Android throws a `SocketTimeoutException` when it is unable to connect to it.

You can manually set the timeout duration of your connection via

`HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, timeoutDuration);`

or let the connection get timed out after its default timeout duration.

So, you can catch that exception in your code and get to know that the web-service is down.

Comment: `HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, timeoutDuration);` this statement is not supported

Comment: it says remove  timeoutduration to match HttpTransportSE... The default timeout duration is too tong

Comment: Quick update.. `timeout` facility us supported only from `Ksoap2 library 2.5.2 ` onwards

Comment: Oh, did not know that.I myself the most updated version of the library anyway. Anyway, glad you got it working. :)